# Is there an adjective meaning "someone who is asking for too much in an arrogant way"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been looking for this word for so long, maybe years. In Bulgarian we use the word *нахален* (nakhalen) or *нагъл* (nagŭl) very often to describe someone who is asking for too much, disregarding people's feelings or objective facts.

For instance, you would use it in the following situations:

1. Your senile grandma can barely walk, but you ask her to carry your groceries home.
2. You tell your friend to give you a ride home without asking them if they have any other plans.
3. When negotiating a salary, you ask for a very high figure for the specific job (e.g. $100,000 for working at KFC).
4. You cut in line, or you don't wait for your turn in general.

Google Translate offers the following translations, but I haven't heard people use them a lot, so I'm not sure which one is suitable for everyday speech:

**insolent, impudent, impertinent, glib, sassy, perky**

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> **Entitled (adj)**: feeling that you have the right to do or have what you want without having to work for it or deserve it, just because of who you are:
>
> Example: These kids are spoiled, entitled, self-absorbed, and apathetic.

— [Cambridge English dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/entitled)

---

An example use at [Times.com](https://time.com/247/millennials-the-me-me-me-generation/)

> May 20, 2013 · I am about to do what old people have done throughout history: call those younger than me lazy, **entitled**, selfish and shallow. But I have studies! I ...

Comment: For the "related to" link: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532892/when-did-the-word-entitled-gain-its-second-sense-of-spoiled

Answer (score 14):

How about **chutzpah**. From Cambridge:

> **[chutzpah](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chutzpah)**: behavior that is extremely confident and often rude, with no respect for the opinions or abilities of anyone else

The situations you describe in your question are all good examples of **chutzpah**.

Comment: This fits the "shamelessly bold" idea which the OP mentions in comments.

Comment: Note that the "ch" in "chutzpah" is pronounced like the Bulgarian "х" in OP's question, or like the German "ch", NOT pronounced as in "chair".

Comment: Chutzpah is a noun (the behavior), not an adjective. I often hear it in phrases like "You have to have a lot of chutzpah to do such and such".

Comment: The corresponding adjective is "chutzpedik."

Comment: Good answer, but I'll note that in contemporary usage, *chutzpah*'s connotation isn't always purely negative (although it traditionally was in its original Yiddish). Nowadays, it can refer to a good kind of boldness or audaciousness, like that of an intrepid explorer or someone who stands up to a bully.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg Thanks. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 11):

I like "brazen" but "inconsiderate" or "entitled" might also fit. Some people act as if they are "entitled" to every desire that crosses their minds.

Comment: "Brazen" works, although it can have positive connotations, depending on the context. Of course, that may be acceptable if the OP wants a word that covers the kinds of situations described in the second paragraph of Max's answer. OTOH, "brazen" doesn't really incorporate the notion of "*asking* for too much".

Answer (score 9):

Someone who is **exploitative** would behave in the way those four situations describe.
[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/exploitative) has

> **exploitative**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> Making use of a situation or treating others unfairly in order to gain an advantage or benefit.
>
> *The details suggested a mean streak, an exploitive nature, a sloppy greediness, none of which seemed especially pleasant, let alone presidential.*
>
> *The yogi forsakes stealing, lying, cheating, killing, and other exploitative and self-gratifying behaviours.*

Answer (score 9):

**demanding** also fits examples 1-3 very well.

Answer (score 8):

As a fellow Bulgarian I can say **insolent** is the closets to *нагъл* in meaning. It is really common in my opinion in books at least. As for *нахален*, something like **cheeky** should do the trick, as it is used less for describing arrogance, more for annoyance.

Comment: True, I guess *entitled*, *presumptuous* and *brazen* are also very close.

Comment: Fellow Romanian agrees with "insolent"

Comment: @BoyanKushlev True enough

Comment: I have to second ```insolent``` solely by the number of times Phineas Nigellus and Severus Snape called Harry insolent in all his years.

Answer (score 6):

I am a native Russian speaker, and in Russian we have the same two words (нахальный, наглый). There are also slang words in my language that carry the same meaning (e.g. борзой). Usually, when someone is acting "нагло", I'd call them out for being *rude*, *entitled*, *inconsiderate*, or *mannerless*. I reckon *insolent* is also an option, but I doubt anyone who doesn't happen to have looked up some of the terms that I have suggested in the thesaurus will even know what this word means. So my suggestion would be to go with one of these four terms.

I must note, however, that, at least in Russian, the word "наглый" can also be applied to situations where something "shamelessly/fearlessly bold" was said or done and often has a rather positive connotation. For example, we might use the word when a footballer scores an outrageous goal, when an inexperienced chess player starts sacrificing pieces against a grandmaster, or when a student proves his teacher wrong in front of the class. In this case, the best translations would certainly be *audacious* and *cheeky*.

Comment: Interesting... I don't think we'd use it with a positive connotation ever, but that would definitely be described as *cheeky* in English.

Comment: The positive connotation is rare in both Russian and Bulgarian, but pretty much present.

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing is someone who considers their own needs so important that any other person's needs do not even come into question. To me, that's 
'arrogance' (arrogant, arrogantly).

Answer (score 3):

I'd say: "That's a selfish bastard."
(Just "selfish" is not strong enough.) Tom Newton Dunn tweeted in September 2018 that Boris Johnson was called exactly this by his daughter Lara.

Answer (score 3):

As a monolingual native English (from England) speaker, I wouldn't say one word fits the 4 descriptions. Below is how I would describe a person for the various situations:

Your senile grandma can barely walk, but you ask her to carry your groceries home:  selfish, or in reference to childish behaviour: a brat (what a spoilt brat!), bratish behaviour.

You tell your friend to give you a ride home without asking them if they have any other plans: selfish, demanding.

When negotiating a salary, you ask for a very high figure for the specific job (e.g. $100,000 for working at KFC): "chutzpah/bold" - if appreciative, "brazen" - if cheeky, "deluded" - is vastly misunderstanding the world or the situation.

You cut in line, or you don't wait for your turn in general: entitled, arrogant, self-centred. Entitled and self-centred denote more their internal mental state or beliefs. Arrogant (also haughty) denote to me their external observable behaviour.

Comment: Hello Paul, and welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The words that comes into my mind that fits Scenario 1,2 and 4 are:

> **1. [Inconsiderate](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/inconsiderate)** (adj)
>
> Not thinking or worrying about other people or their feelings
>
> **2. [Tactless](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/tactless)** (adj)
>
> Someone who is tactless is not careful about the way that they speak or behave toward other people and so often upsets them

Meanwhile, for Scenario 3, I would go for

> **[Presumptuous](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/presumptuous)** (adj)
>
> Showing too much confidence and not enough respect

Answer (score 2):

Someone who continually caters to their own needs and doesn't even have how their behavior and demand affect others on their radar is *egotistical* and *narcissistic*.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *imperious, bumptious and overbearing*.

> **Imperious (adj):** unpleasantly proud and expecting to be obeyed.
>
> Examples:
>
> - An imperious manner/voice
> - She sent them away with an imperious wave of the hand.

— [Cambridge English dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/imperious)

---

> **Bumptious (adj):** unpleasantly confident.
>
> Example: A bumptious young man

— [Cambridge English dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bumptious)

---

> **Overbearing (adj):** too confident and too determined to tell other people what to do, in a way that is unpleasant.
>
> Example: Milligan had a pompous, overbearing father.

— [Cambridge English dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/overbearing)

<sub>Or *[domineering](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/domineering)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I recently did a reading of The Great Gatsby with a book club and I'll say that **supercilious** would be a good adjective here. Not the act of asking but the kind of person doing the asking. The request would be more or less perfunctory in that he's not requesting but telling you what you will do but phrasing it as a request.

Answer (score 0):

## Tacky

While you use "arrogant" in the title, your question implies the Bulgarian word is more on the apathetic side. Tacky typically does not fall into the arrogant category. The four scenarios you describe could all be described as "tacky". [Cambridge has this definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tacky) (emphasis mine)

> of cheap quality or **in bad style**

It's not necessarily arrogant, but it is apathetic to the plight of the people around the subject. Put another way, the person has no shame about doing something that will socially irritate others.

Weird Al Yankovic has a [perfect illustration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zq7Eki5EZ8o) if you need one